# IOS SoundCloud, Fetching Logged User Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, soundcloud

I am trying to integrate SoundCloud to my IOS application so that I can upload and download the songs from and into my app. So far I have completed uploading and downloading songs but I want to retrieve User Data after successful login. [I have followed this API documentation](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/ios-quickstart)

How can I retrieve user data after user has logged in successfully?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the official SoundCloud iOS SDK I think you need this method in the SCRequest class:

```
+ (id)   performMethod:(SCRequestMethod)aMethod
        onResource:(NSURL *)resource
   usingParameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters
       withAccount:(SCAccount *)account
sendingProgressHandler:(SCRequestSendingProgressHandler)progressHandler
   responseHandler:(SCRequestResponseHandler)responseHandler;

+ (void)cancelRequest:(id)request;
```

Just open the SCRequest.h and SCRequest.m and I'm sure you find what you're looking for.